# How to configure Eclipse CDT to compile code containing the mongocxx driver in Linux?

Tags: eclipse, mongodb, eclipse-cdt

I'm trying to configure eclipse cdt to compile code that contains the mongocxx driver. This code is from mongo's installation page. The same errors I am getting on my own project are clearly displayed here. The includes are recognized but I believe that it is a linker issue.

```
#include <iostream>

#include <bsoncxx/builder/stream/document.hpp>
#include <bsoncxx/json.hpp>

#include <mongocxx/client.hpp>
#include <mongocxx/instance.hpp>

int main(int, char**) {
    mongocxx::instance inst{}; 
    mongocxx::client conn{mongocxx::uri{}};

    bsoncxx::builder::stream::document document{};

    auto collection = conn["testdb"]["testcollection"];
    document << "hello" << "world";

    collection.insert_one(document.view());
    auto cursor = collection.find({});

    for (auto&& doc : cursor) {
        std::cout << bsoncxx::to_json(doc) << std::endl;
    }
}
```

[This is my actual screenshot with errors from my IDE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YIsCc.png)

Comment: Please don't post screenshots - copy and paste the text.

Comment: 1) Have you tried rebuilding the index? 2) What are the error messages for those errors?

Comment: Were you able to resolve this?

Comment: Yes! It worked when I rebuilt the index.